# CSS Height of 'input type=text' zone

Tags: css, input, height

HTML/CSS problem.
I've been writing a web application for several days. I meet a little problem:

The height of any "`input type=text`" zone has suddenly turned to about 35 pixel high, meanwhile it used to be about just 20. The strange thing is that I think I changed nothing in my code for it to happen.

So, by the way, does anyone know a way to change the height of that zone (it seems the CSS "height" property has no effect, unless I misused it)?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: pls share sample code... i will check and let you know

Comment: Can you share you code snippet and a photo of that behavior, please? :)

Comment: correct, `height` won't work if you didn't change that, but did you also try `padding`?, this might be causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're not able to change the height property (except maybe by using !important), I assume that you're using a css framework like f.e. bootstrap which gives ur inputs a specific height or maybe (more possible) a padding.

But please, be aware of sharing some code in order for us to understand what you're looking for.

EDIT: Given your screenshot, I really assume that all of your inputs have a certain padding. please check that out.

Comment: Thanks for your help. No, i use no framework at all, having written my own methods over the years. So everything here is basic CSS without any "blackbox".

Comment: Could you please still check if whether your inputs or your text alongside the inputs have a padding or margin? (In Chrome f.e. with Ctrl + Shift + I, selecting the arrow and going over some elements)

Comment: the problem was "height" itself, and I found no "padding" through the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's an image for example. The code is several thousand lines long, but that height problem now appears on all inputs in the application. thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry if the code I have to insert is a little bit long, but the app is quite long indeed.
So here are 2 parts:
1 : The global CSS sheet of the application

2 : An HTML object where I meet the problem

---

PART 1 - CSS - THE GLOBAL CSS SHEET OF THE APPLICATION:

```
body {margin:0;font-family:'Helvetica';font-size:0.8em;color:black;background-color:#DDD;}
        a {text-decoration:none;color:black;padding:3px 20px;}
        a:hover {color:#FFF;background-image:url('../images/curseur.jpg');}
        button {margin:0;padding:0;}  
        .creux {border:2px solid;border-top-color:#666;border-left-color:#666;border-right-color:#FFF;border-bottom-color:#FFF;}            
        .relief {border:2px solid;border-top-color:#EEE;border-left-color:#EEE;border-right-color:#666;border-bottom-color:#666;}
        .lien {color:#008;text-decoration:underline;cursor:pointer;}
        .boutIcone {padding:0;width:20px;height:20px;border:2px solid;border-top-color:#EEE;border-left-color:#EEE;border-right-color:#666;border-bottom-color:#666;}
        .imBouton {position:relative;left:0px;top:-1px;width:16px;}
        .fl {float:left}
        .libIn {float:left;text-align:right}
        input {height:20px;}

        #ecran {position: absolute;top: 0;width: 100%;height:850px;background-color: #FFF;}
            /*bandeau*/
             #bandeau {position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;height:72px;text-align:center;font-family:'Tahoma';}
                #imBandeau {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;}
                #logo {position:absolute;top:3px;left:3px;width:150px;height:60px;}
                /* etiquette */
                 #etiquette {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%}
                    #titre {position:relative;font-size:2em;font-weight:bold;top:7px;}
                    #sousTitre {position:relative;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;top:5px;}
                    #signature {position:relative;font-size:9px;top:6px;font-family:Helvetica;font-weight:200;}
                /* fin etiquette */                 
            /* fin bandeau */

            /* gestion des menus */
             #espaceMenus {position:absolute;top:0;width:100%;z-index:12;}
                #barreMenu {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:34px;font-size:16px;border:0;font-family:Tahoma}
                #barreTexte {position:relative;top:-30px;left:2px;padding:2px 0;}
                #barreTexte a{display:inline;padding:4px 20px;}
                #barreFond {width:100%;height:30px;}
                #menus {position:absolute;top:27px;z-index:14;font-size:16px}
                #menus a {display:block;position:relative;padding:4px 3px;z-index:14}                                
                .icoMenu {border:0;padding: 1px 3px 0 0;margin:0 0 -4px;}
                .logoMenu {position:relative;float:right;border:0;top:2px;} 
                .barreMx {position:absolute;top:6px;width:25em;background-image:url('../images/plaqueFond.jpg');border-right:2px solid;border-bottom:2px solid;border-right-color:#666;border-bottom-color:#666;z-index:13;}
                .barreMxMx {background-image:url('../images/plaquefond.jpg');width:25em;position: absolute;top:30px;margin:0.35em 0 0.5em 0;z-index:13;}
            /*fin gestion des menus */  

            /* barre de titre */            
                .barreTitre {height:24px;background-image:url('../images/barretitre.jpg');color:#21B;font-weight:bold;font-size:12px;}
                .titreBarre {position:relative;margin:10px;top:3px;}
                .rtBout {position:relative;width:22px;height:22px;float:right;border:2px solid;border-top-color:#EEE;border-left-color:#EEE;border-right-color:#666;border-bottom-color:#666;}
                .lfIcon {position:relative;left:2px;top:3px;float:left;}
            /* Fin barre de titre ------------ */           

            /* Objets génériques du gridview */
             #tbFiltre {position:absolute;background-color:#DFD;width:700px;left:25%;top:100px;float:left;font-size:0.9em;}
             #tbFiltre td {background-color:#EEE; }
             #rubriques td {text-align:center;}
             .gvEntete {width:100%;height:25px;font-weight:bold;}
             .gvLigTit {background-color:#D8D8D8}   /* lignes de titres */
             .gvLig0 {background-color:#DDD}        /* lignes paires du gridview */ 
             .gvLig1 {background-color:#FFF}        /* lignes impaires du gridview */ 
             .gvTableau {position:relative;border-spacing:0px;width:100%;border:1px solid #000;border-collapse:collapse;}
             .gvTableau td {height:12px;border:1px solid #000;font-family: arial;font-size:0.8em;height:14px;}
             /* #barreCol {z-index:11;position:absolute;top:45px;} */
             /* fin Objets génériques du gridview */    

             /* --- Calendrier --- */
                .calend {border-collapse:collapse;}
                .calend td {border:1px solid black;text-align:center;}
                .calMouv {background-color:#BBA; color:#FFF;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;}
                .calMouv button{width:100%;font-size:0.70em;}    
                .semaine {font-style:italic;color:#070;text-align:center;font-weight:bold;width:33px;}
                .colRouge {font-weight:bold;color:#A00;}    
            /* --- fin du calendrier --- */

             #messAttente {position:fixed;top:300px;left:340px;width:340px; height:80px; background-color:#DDE; z-index:7; display:none;}

           /* ----- Menus versatiles composés à partir d'une Apile ------ */
           .menuVersat {font-size:14px}

           /* ------------------- Page de recherche html -------------------*/
            .lienRecherche {font-weight: bold;text-decoration: underline;color: blue;}
            .lbCreux {position:relative;color:#FFE;border:2px solid;border-top-color:#666;border-left-color:#666;border-right-color:#FFF;border-bottom-color:#FFF;}     
            #salut{position:relative;top:40px;margin-left:10px}



    PART 2 - HTML - THE DIV "MODLOCAT" THAT I WAS WRITING WHEN THE PROBLEM OCCURRED: 

    <div id="modLocat" class="relief" style="width:750px;height:560px;background-color:#EEE;">
    <!-- barre de titre -->
    <div id='barTit' class='barreTitre' style='width:100%;'>
        <img src='icones/MonMotif.ico' class='lfIcon'>
        <button class='rtBout' onclick='popFen();'><img src='icones/croixrouge.ico'></button>
        <button class='rtBout' onclick='passeEcrEch();'><img src='icones/encochevertolive.ico' title="Passer les écritures sélectionnées"></button>
        <span class='titreBarre'>Modification de location</span>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- fin de la barre de titre -->
    <br>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Locataire: &nbsp;</div>
    <select id='ddLoc' class='ddl' onchange='selLoc();' style='float:left;width:180px;' size='1'> </select>
    <button class='boutIcone' style="position:relative;left:3px;float:left;top:-2px" onclick='modifLocation();'><img src='icones/croixrouge.ico'></button>
    <div style="float:left;width:20px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="float:left;position:relative;left:5px">Appartement:&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="dic..appart$" class="lbCreux" style="float:left;width:340px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Prénom: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..prenom%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:150px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:70px">Nom: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..nom%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:150px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:160px">Date de naissance: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..deta_d_naissance%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:104px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Employeur: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..employeur%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:450px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:71px">Salaire: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..salaire%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:120px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Caution: &nbsp;</div>
    <textarea id='dic..caution%' rows='5' cols='200' style='position:relative; float:left;width:648px; height:90px;'></textarea>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Aide CAF: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..aide_caf%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:100px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:120px">Date d'entrée &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..date_entree%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:90px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:120px">Date de sortie: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..date_sortie%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:90px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Loyer HC: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..loyer_assume%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:70px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:70px">Loyer CC: &nbsp;</div>
    <input id="dic..loyer_global%" style="position:relative;float:left;width:70px;height:18px" type="text">
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-`enter code here`align:right;width:140px">Date Dern. ope.: &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="dic..date_dern_ope$" class="lbCreux" style="float:left;width:70px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:120px">Solde du compte: &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="dic..solde$" class="lbCreux" style="float:left;width:76px">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
    <div style="position:relative;float:left;margin-left:7px;text-align:right;width:80px">Remarques: &nbsp;</div>
    <textarea id='dic..txRem%' rows='5' cols='200' style='position:relative; float:left;width:647px; height:230px;'></textarea>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I had added input {height:20px} into the global CSS sheet, but didn't remember that. And the effect was immediate, so it was not 35 px instead of 20, but 20 instead of 14.

So we may conclude that we can set the "height" property on then "input type=text" objects, so I was wrong to think it had no effect.